# Docusign: creating envelopes through templates with the REST API and prefilling tags

Tags: docusignapi

I'm integrating Docusign so that recipients can see their envelopes embedded on my site. I first create the envelope with the api, and I'm attempting to prefill Data Fields using dynamic data.

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with my json that I'm using to create the envelopes. None of the other solutions on StackOverflow to this issue have helped. My json looks like this (which I send to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/360734/envelopes):

```
{
   "status": "sent",
   "emailBlurb": "Please sign the document.",
   "emailSubject": "Please sign your agreement",
   "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID",
   "templateRoles": [
     {
       "clientUserId": "EMAIL",
       "name": "NAME",
       "email": "EMAIL",
       "roleName": "Signer1",
       "tabs": {
         "textTabs": [
           {
             "tabLabel": "address",
             "value": "ADDRESS "
           },
           {
             "tabLabel": "multi_address",
             "value": "ADDRESSES"
           }
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "name": "ANOTHER NAME",
       "email": "ANOTHER EMAIL",
       "roleName": "Random1"
     }
   ]
 }
```

And I get the following response:

```
{
   "envelopeId": "ENVELOPE_ID",
   "uri": "/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID",
   "statusDateTime": "2013-10-25T01:20:55.6750772Z",
   "status": "sent"
}
```

I then get the link to show the client by posting to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/360734/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/views/recipient

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "clientUserId": "EMAIL",
  "email": "EMAIL",
  "returnUrl": "MYURL",
  "userName": "NAME"
}
```

And I get this response:

```
 {
   "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?t=REDACTED"
 }
```

This follows the example seen here: https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013/blob/master/example2.json

After creating the envelope this way, it appears that the tags do not prefill. When I view the envelope embedded on my site, nothing is filled. I'm certain the tabLabels are correct. Everything otherwise seems to be working okay. Is there some kind of setting I'm missing?

**UPDATE**
Looks like it could be a bug! All I change is the role name and it works!

```
 {
   "status": "sent",
   "emailBlurb": "Please sign the document.",
   "emailSubject": "Please sign your agreement",
   "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID",
   "templateRoles": [
     {
       "clientUserId": "EMAIL",
       "name": "NAME",
       "email": "EMAIL",
       "roleName": "Signer1",
       "tabs": {
         "textTabs": [
           {
             "tabLabel": "address",
             "value": "ADDRESS "
           },
           {
             "tabLabel": "multi_address",
             "value": "ADDRESSES"
           }
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "name": "ANOTHER NAME",
       "email": "ANOTHER EMAIL",
       "roleName": "Signer2"
     }
   ]
 }
```

And it populated! It seems if I start the role name with anything other than Signer it doesn't work. Weird!

And yes, I'm changing the role name on Docusign from Random1 to Signer2, in this case. For example, Signer3 also worked.

Answer (score 7):

Your question says your submitting that JSON to the "Get Recipient View" resource:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/views/recipient)
```

...but that JSON looks like what you use in the "Create Envelope" request, not the "Get Recipient View" request.  So, let me start by clarifying the process of facilitating Embedded/captive signing (i.e., presenting the recipient's envelope within your site). Doing so is a two-step process:

**STEP 1**: Create the envelope (request includes data to pre-populate fields for each recipient, if needed).

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

See "Creating an Envelope From a Template" section that starts on p27 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for detailed info about request and response.

**STEP 2**: Retrieve the URL that can be used to launch the recipient's envelope (signing session).

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

{
"authenticationMethod":"Email",
"clientUserId":"CLIENT_USERID_SPECIFIED_IN_REQUEST",
"email":"RECIPIENT_EMAIL",
"returnUrl":"URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO_WHEN_SIGNING_COMPLETE",
"userName":"RECIPIENT_NAME"
}
```

The response will contain the URL that can be used to launch the Recipient's Envelope:

```
{
"url":"URL_THAT_WILL_LAUNCH_ENVELOPE"
}
```

See the "Post Recipient View" section that starts on p160 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for more detailed info about request and response.

Now, assuming you're doing all this correctly (step 1 and step 2) -- let's get back to the issue you're reporting: difficulty pre-populating fields for the recipient.  A few comments about the "Create Envelope from Template" JSON that you included in your question:

- You don't need **accountId** in request.
- You don't need to include **documentId** and **pageNumber** in the request for the tab.
- You DO need to include **clientUserId** for the recipient in the request, if you want the recipient to sign embedded/captive within your site.

So, here's a "Create/Send Envelope From Template" example request (**step 1** above) that pre-populates the tab named "FIELD_1" with the value "VALUE_A" anywhere that it appears in the envelope:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes
{
    "status"        : "sent",
    "emailBlurb"    : "please sign",
    "emailSubject"  : "Please sign your document",
    "templateId"    : "TEMPLATE_ID",
    "templateRoles" : [{
      "name"         : "John Doe",
      "email"        : "JohnsEmail@outlook.com",
      "roleName"     : "Signer1Role",
      "clientUserId" : "123",
      "tabs"         :
         {"textTabs":[{
            "tabLabel":"\\*FIELD_1",
            "value":"VALUE_A"}
         ]}
   }]
}
```

Then, you'd take the Envelope Id that's returned in the response and call the "Get Recipient View" resource (**step 2** above) to get the URL to launch the signing session:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/views/recipient
{
     "authenticationMethod": "Email",
     "clientUserId": "123",
     "userName": "John Doe",
     "email": "JohnsEmail@outlook.com",
     "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

Finally, one last comment (but an important one): if you're just wanting to inject the recipient's "full name" in the document -- use the "**Full Name**" tab when creating the Template and DocuSign will automatically inject the recipient's name in place of that tag, anywhere that it appears (instead of you using a Text Tab and having to populate it via the API request). Here's the **Full Name** tag in the DocuSign UI tagger view:
[image: Using Full Name tag]

**Another Create Envelope Example (with screenshot of data field properties**):

If I submit this request:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes
{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this",
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
  "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID",
  "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
  "templateRoles": [
   {
      "roleName": "Signer1",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "JohnsEmail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "tabs":{
            "textTabs":[
               {
                  "tabLabel":"\\*address",
                  "value":"123 Main Street"
               },
            ],
         }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

And the Data Field properties (when Editing the Template via the DocuSign UI) look like this:

[image: Data Field Properties]

Then the result is that field(s) with Label = **address** that are assigned to Recipient Role **Signer1** will be prepopulated with the value "123 Main Street" when the signer views their envelope.  If this isn't working for you, I suggest that you:

- Verify that the value of **roleName** in the API request *exactly* matches the Recipient value I've highlighted in the prior screenshot (in my example, "Signer1").
- Verify that the value of **tabLabel** in the API request *exactly* matches the Label value I've highlighted in the prior screenshot (in my example, "address).

***Note***: Values are ***case-sensitive***, so be sure values in your request are an ***exact*** match (including upper-case/lower-case) with the values in the Data Field Tag Properties.

Comment: Thank you for the help! You're right, I posted the wrong URL.

I switched to using Full Name where possible, very helpful. That is populating for the user, embedded on my site. I still have the address to prepopulate, which I made a data field. It still won't prepopulate, even though the label is "address", and I'm sending json like

`"tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                  {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*address",
                    "value": "123 Fake Street"
                  }
                ]
              }`

Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I've edited my prior answer to add a second example Request, this time including screenshot of the corresponding data field tab properties in the Template.  Values are case-sensitive -- so be sure values in your request are an exact match (including upper-case/lower-case) with the values in the Data Field Tag Properties.  For example, if your request has "tabLabel" = "address" (lower-case "a") and the value of "Label" for the Data Field in the Template is set to "Address" (upper-case "A"), then the field(s) would not be populated by the request.

Comment: Is recipientId necessary? (I've tried adding it but it made no difference)

Comment: Thanks much for the help, I've paid close attention to the instructions you gave, but the data fields just don't seem to populate for me. Is there anyway to work with someone from DocuSign to look at my specific case?

Comment: Dan can you please edit your answer so that it has the latest, correct info in it?  It's hard to tell what your latest full JSON is, which URL you're using, etc.  Please list your JSON, and let us know what fields you have setup in your template including their label value.

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I've updated my original post to be accurate and up to date. It's very odd... I change the role name on the template and in my json, and suddenly the Data Fields populate. Beats me...

Comment: FWIW, I'm unable to repro the issue you describe -- i.e., I can specify roleName=Random1 and it works just fine for me (fields are populated for signer as specified in the API request). As long as spelling, case (uppercase/lowercase), and spacing match exactly between roleName in your API Request and Role Name in the Template, it shouldn't matter what the value of Role Name is.